# Trying to create simple json object of 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I'm just learning jason and nothings working.  I'm trying to creat a object with 3 arrays.   I tried top do it 2 ways

this.serverReply={
                      parent:
               {comments: ["ted","pop"]},
               {links:["link1","link2"]},
               {Dates:["link1","link2"]}
           };

and

```
          this.serverReply={          
           {comments: ["ted","pop"]},
           {links:["link1","link2"]},
           {Dates:["link1","link2"]}
       };
```

I get a syntex error saying invalid propery.  I cannot figure out why,
Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every property of an object needs to have a name, which is specified like this:

```
var obj = { name: "value", another: "value2" };
```

Arrays are specified with square brackets, and do not have named elements:

```
var arr = ["value", "value2"];
```

From that point on, it depends on what you want to do. In both your examples you try to specify object properties without giving them names. Try this instead:

```
this.serverReply={
    comments: ["ted","pop"], 
    links:["link1","link2"], 
    dates:["link1","link2"]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes them all, you will be able to use any key and value, includes javascript keywords.

```
this.serverReply={
    "comments": ["ted","pop"], 
    "links":["link1","link2"], 
    "dates":["link1","link2"]
};
```